# Best Practice for Creating New Record with belongsTo Relationship

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am wondering about the best practice for creating a new record in Ember with `createRecord()` and then persisting it to the API?  Specifically, should Ember's `POST` request generally be a single JSON that embeds all the model's relationships, or is it customary to `POST` each relationship individually?

In my code, I'm not able to get a single JSON, so I'm wondering if I'm missing the "Ember Way" or (more likely) I have a mistake in my code?

**DETAILS:**

Here are the details of my setup. I have two models:

**/models/OrgUser.js:**

```
DS.Model.extend({
    ...
    orgPerson: DS.belongsTo('org-person', { inverse: 'org-user', async: true, embedded: 'always' }),
});
```

**/models/OrgPerson.js:**

```
DS.Model.extend({
   ...
   orgUser: DS.belongsTo('org-user'),
})
```

I'm attempting to create a new user on the "Create New User" page.  The route for that page is below. Is this the best place to call `createRecord()` for my new models?

**/routes/org-users/add.js:**

```
Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        var orgPerson = this.store.createRecord('org-person');
        var orgUser = this.store.createRecord('org-user' );
        orgUser.set('orgPerson', orgPerson);

        return orgUser;
    },
     ...
}
```

Using Chrome console to look at the orgUser object after I call `set` shows no evidence at all that I have added anything to `orgUser`. The "Ember" tab of Chrome Debug Tools does reflect the relationship, though.

On my "Create New User" page, my input fields all correspond to both `OrgUser` properties and `OrgUser.OrgPerson` properties.  Here's an example:

**/templates/org-users/add.hbs**

```
...
{{input value=username}} // a property of OrgUser
{{input value=orgPerson.firstName}} // a property of OrgUser.orgPerson
...
```

In my route, when I go to `save()` Ember Data `POST`s only the orgUser JSON with a `null` value for `orgPerson.` I'd like it to embed the `orgPerson` serialized object in the `orgPerson` property.

**/routes/org-users/add.js:**

```
Ember.Route.extend({
    ...
    actions: {
        submitForm: function() {
            ...
            this.currentModel.save().then( onSuccess ).catch( onFailure );
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

This results in a `POST` request with the following body:

```
{
"orgUser":{
   "username":"MyUsername",
   "orgPerson":null,
   "id":null
}
```

Note that `orgPerson` is null.  Thanks in advance for any assistance!

**UPDATE:** Once again, I think I will need to take a fresh look at my serializer.  Here's how it's currently defined.

**/serializers/application.js:**

```
DS.RESTSerializer.extend({

    // Use the default approach to serializing, but add the id property
    serialize: function(record, options) {
        var json = this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        json.id = record.id;
        return json;
    },

    serializeBelongsTo: function(record, json, relationship) {
    var key = relationship.key;
      key = this.keyForRelationship ? this.keyForRelationship(key, 'belongsTo') : key;

      var data = record.get('data');

      if (relationship.options.embedded && relationship.options.embedded === 'always') {
        json[key] = data[relationship.key] ? data[relationship.key].serialize( { includeId: true } ) : null;
        }
      else {
            json[key] = data[relationship.key] ? data[relationship.key].get('id') : null;
        }

        if (relationship.options.polymorphic) {
            this.serializePolymorphicType(record, json, relationship);
        }
    }
});
```

Per @Kingpin2k's comment, there appears to be some ambiguity (and bugs!) on how best to handle `serialize()` for a `belongsTo` relationship. My serializer customization above works great for records that are obtained through `this.store.find()`, but now I need to enable them for `createRecord()`.  Additional suggestions, pointers are welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I finally figured this out. With the release of Ember-Data-1.0.0-Beta.9, http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/08/18/ember-data-1-0-beta-9-released.html, the `EmbeddedRecordsMixin` has been introduced.  This pretty much solves all my issues!

So, I wound up doing the following:

- Upgraded to Ember-Data-1.0.0-Beta.9
- Deleted my `serializeBelongsTo` customization from my serializer
- I now define a custom serializer for each model using the `EmbeddedRecordsMixin` as documented at http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html.

This wound up working perfectly, because I get full declarative control over how and when my records are embedded.

Special thanks to @Kingpin2k for helping me realize my serializer was the problem and for the discussion to help me understand the options.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug.  https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1542#issuecomment-49443496

A workaround is to get the async belongsTo record before attempting to save (It tricks Ember Data into initializing it).  In your case you could do it in the model hook.

```
model: function() {
    var orgPerson = this.store.createRecord('org-person');
    var orgUser = this.store.createRecord('org-user');
    orgUser.set('orgPerson', orgPerson);
    return orgUser.get('orgPerson').then(function(){
      return orgUser;
    });
},
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Kingpin2k. This didn't seem to resolve my issue. I even temporarily deleted all my serializer customizations and still had the same issue. The fact that it's buggy at all, though, changes my mindset, so I'm going to use Debug mode in IntelliJ + Chrome to better understand what's happening and will report back.  If you have any other suggestions on areas to look at, or working examples, feel free to share.  Thanks!

Comment: Updated original post with my serializer.

Comment: I'll have to check it out when I'm back on my computer. Ember data has been fighting with async relationships for what feels like a year.

Comment: Thanks @Kingpin2k. I'm curious to see what you conclude. Yeah, even the recommendation on whether to use async at all seems ambiguous. Based on https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1443#issuecomment-26607013, I opted to use `async:true` for every relationship, but to your point, it doesn't always play nice. Hopefully, this resolution can be as simple as a better set of `Serializer` method definitions; all my issues with async so far have stemmed either from (1) the fact that I thought I'd get the model itself but instead got a promise, or (2) the serializer not doing what I expect.

Comment: Quick update. It's definitely the serializer. I implemented this http://mozmonkey.com/2013/12/serializing-embedded-relationships-ember-data-beta/ and now my `createRecord` works fine, but my existing models fail. So, I think the solution is just working out what the right serializer should be. Will post solution when I implement it.

Comment: Sorry, I got sidetracked by some other work, it looks like the async relationship is stored in the meta data for the record.  There are probably quite a few edge cases here, but here's what it looks like so far: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/952/edit, the tricky thing is you don't want to use a getter or you can force the async relationship to fetch when it may not be needed...  So I'm going to keep breaking this for a few minutes, in the same jsbin

Comment: At the same time, I'm not sure what type of response you're looking for if the record hasn't ever been fetched... lots of options

Comment: Thank you so much for your assistance. It is really appreciated. My objective at this point is to have a `RESTSerializer` that can successfully serialize a `belongsTo` relationship, whether that record comes from a `createRecord()` or a `find()` (which produces records in two different state). I saw that Ember-Data-1.0.0-Beta.9 was released yesterday, so my plan is (1) remove all my `RESTSerializer` customizations and try the new `EmbeddedRecordMixin`, (2) or if that fails, rewrite the `RESTSerializer`, taking inspiration from your JSBin. Working on this now and will post updates. Thx again!

Comment: Definitely a smart move, staying up with the latest versions until it hits a stable version will be a life saver for the future if you ever need to update...